# Syntax error with insert into statement - Works in Access DB not in VS2010 vb prog

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I am having a problem with the insertion of data into Access Database, this works fine for all my other tables, yet it just doesn't want to insert for my one table, this might be some silly syntax error that is totally making me pull my hair out, can someone please advise what I might be doing wrong here, please dont mind my coding I am a complete novice. Everytime I run the code I get an syntax error insert into statement error.When I run this in Access it inserts the data no problem but when I run it in VB I get the syntax error I have no idea what is wrong here, can you perhaps advise

```
     Sub Insert_NewUser(ByVal txtUserID As TextBox, ByVal txtUser_Name As     TextBox, ByVal txtFullName As TextBox, ByVal txtPassword As TextBox, ByVal txtPassword2 As TextBox, ByVal cmbUser_Type As ComboBox)

    Dim UserID, User_Name As String
    Dim FullName, Password, Password2 As String
    Dim User_Type As String
    UserID = txtUserID.Text
    User_Name = txtUser_Name.Text
    FullName = txtFullName.Text
    Password = txtPassword.Text
    Pass_confirmed= txtPassword2.Text
    User_Type = cmbUser_Type.SelectedItem

    con.Open()
    Dim Sql As String = "Insert INTO Users(UserID,User_Name,FullName,Password,Pass_confirmed,User_Type)VALUES(@UserID,@User_Name,@FullName,@Password,@Pass_confirmed,@User_Type)"
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(Sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Name", User_Name)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", FullName)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass_confirmed", Pass_confirmed)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Type", User_Type)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please update the question with the syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually caused by *Password* being a reserved word, thus it needs to be bracketed:

```
Dim Sql As String = "Insert INTO Users(UserID,User_Name,FullName,[Password],Pass_confirmed,User_Type)VALUES(@UserID,@User_Name,@FullName,@Password,@Pass_confirmed,@User_Type)"
```